# trying to decrypt via php a password that i encrypted with javav

Tags: java, php, encryption, mcrypt

so my java looks like

```
String epassword = Crypt.encryptStringToString((String) params.get("password"));
```

I then store that in a DB. I need to decrypt it with PHP.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you storing an encrypted password in your database?  If it's a user's password it should be salted and hashed.

Comment: I appreciate your opinion but that was not the question or was i asking for your opinion on how to save passwords. I have a legacy problem i am trying to solve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using `uk.org.ellery.twiki.Crypt`, since that's the only thing that came up when I search on Google for "encryptStringToString java".

In PHP, you will need to re-implement the class linked here:

http://svn.foswiki.org/trunk/EncryptedPagesPlugin/uk/org/ellery/twiki/Crypt.java

You're specifically interested in the "decryptString" method.

If it helps, looks like it generates a random salt which is stored with the encrypted value in the first 8 bytes, and the algorithm to apply the actual encryption/decryption is "PBEWithMD5AndDES", as provided by the standard Java crypto libraries. However, there's some wrapper code to convert values into hex values and a Base64 string (and vice versa).

Looks like [someone has already ported PBEWithMD5AndDES to PHP](https://github.com/KevinBusse/PBEWithMD5AndDES), so you just need to re-write the Crypt.java file in PHP.

Comment: Thanks for hinting to my port of the Algorithm, I finally got around to add decryption as well.